# Why only a small number of threads are launching?

Tags: c, algorithm, cuda

The code is for parallelizing string matching algorithm (brute force). Why only 5 threads are launching instead of 17?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

__global__ void pattern_search(char* d_txt,char* d_pat,int* d_result,int N,int M){
    int id=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if(id<=(N)){
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            if(d_txt[id+j]!=d_pat[j]){
                break;
            }
        }
        //if(j==M){
            d_result[id]=id;
        //}

    }
}

int main(){
    char txt[]="AABAACAADAABAAABAA";
    char pat[]="AABA";

    int N=strlen(txt);
    int M=strlen(pat);
    char* d_pat;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pat,M);
    char* d_txt;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_txt,N);

    int result[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        result[i]=0;
    }

    int* d_result;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_result,N);
    cudaMemcpy(d_txt,txt,N,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_pat,pat,M,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_result,result,N,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    pattern_search<<<1,50>>>(d_txt,d_pat,d_result,N,M);

    cudaMemcpy(result,d_result,N,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int k=0;k<N;k++){

        printf("pattern found at:%d\n",result[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, it's good practice to demonstrate and use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) **and** run your code with `cuda-memcheck`.  If you had run this code with `cuda-memcheck`, it would have reported errors that might be instructive.
2. It's not clear why you would ask about 17 threads.  In CUDA, the number of threads launched can be deduced from the kernel launch, and in brief it is the product of the first two numbers in the kernel launch configuration (`<<<...>>>`):

   ```
   pattern_search<<<1,50>>>(d_txt,d_pat,d_result,N,M);
   ```

   so in this case, it should launch 50 threads.  Even if your question is restricted to `N`, the number `N` for your posted code is 18, not 17.
3. `cudaMalloc`, like host-side `malloc`, allocates memory in *bytes*.  Therefore usage like this is not correct for this case:

   ```
   cudaMalloc((void**)&d_result,N);
   ```

   and instead you should do something like this:

   ```
   cudaMalloc((void**)&d_result,N*sizeof(int));
   ```

   since in this case you want to store `N` quantities of size `int`.  This error was discoverable with `cuda-memcheck` which would report invalid `__global__` writes as a result of this allocation error.
4. A similar problem occurs on your `cudaMemcpy` calls, which also operate on *bytes* (just like host `memcpy`).  Instead of this:

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(d_result,result,N,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   ```

   we want this:

   ```
   cudaMemcpy(d_result,result,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   ```

   and a similar correction needs to be made on the call after the kernel.
5. Your kernel has an out-of-bounds indexing error:

   ```
   if(id<=(N)){
       int j=0;
       for(j=0;j<M;j++){
           if(d_txt[id+j]!=d_pat[j]){
   ```

   the above code will allow the for-loop to index beyond the end of the array `d_txt` which is limited to length `N`.  To fix this we can restrict the loop behavior to only operate if there is enough "indexing room" for the full iteration of the j-loop:

   ```
   if((id+M)<=(N)){
       int j=0;
       for(j=0;j<M;j++){
           if(d_txt[id+j]!=d_pat[j]){
   ```

   (and there are probably many other ways to address this as well.)  This error could have been spotted by the invalid `__global__` reads reported by `cuda-memcheck`.

The following code has the above items addressed, and runs without error for me:

```
$ cat t964.cu
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


__global__ void pattern_search(char* d_txt,char* d_pat,int* d_result,int N,int M){
    int id=threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if((id+M)<=(N)){
        int j=0;
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            if(d_txt[id+j]!=d_pat[j]){
                break;
            }
        }
        //if(j==M){
            d_result[id]=id;
        //}

    }
}

int main(){
    char txt[]="AABAACAADAABAAABAA";
    char pat[]="AABA";

    int N=strlen(txt);
    int M=strlen(pat);
    char* d_pat;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pat,M);
    char* d_txt;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_txt,N);

    int result[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        result[i]=0;
    }

    int* d_result;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_result,N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_txt,txt,N,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_pat,pat,M,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_result,result,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("1");
    pattern_search<<<1,50>>>(d_txt,d_pat,d_result,N,M);

    cudaMemcpy(result,d_result,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("2");
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++){

        printf("pattern found at:%d\n",result[k]);
    }
}
```

You haven't indicated exactly what output you expect, but the results seem plausible to me.

Note that my applied fix for item 5 above means that only the first `N-M+1` threads will report results.  If you wanted some sort of different behavior (not sure exactly what sort of pattern matching you want) there would be other ways to modify this, of course.

In the future, if you want to avoid down-votes and close-votes, my suggestion would be to note that your question is essentially asking for debugging assistance ("Why isn't this code working?") and so it falls into a category of questions for which SO [expects](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You provided a complete code, which is good.  There are probably a few other things that could be improved:

1. State more clearly what the problem is.  The question about how many threads are running is not very clear.  For a good MCVE, you should explain what the expected results are and show the actual results.  In some cases it may also be useful to mention the CUDA version, the compile command line, and the platform (host operating system) you are using.
2. Demonstrate and use proper cuda error checking and use of `cuda-memcheck`.  Even if you don't understand the error output, describe or include it in your question -- it will be useful for others who are trying to help you.